# Swift: Why is the answer to this Swift Challenge -3?

Tags: swift

**Swift Language Question**

Hi guys, I am new to programming so I appreciate your patience. I am currently learning through various platforms. Below was a question that I got right but I don't understand why.

I would appreciate anyones help if you could explain the answer to me.

What is the value of "c"?

```
    var a = 3
    let b = a++
    let c = -b
```

The answer is -3 but I don't know why. The significance I know is in the difference between b and c being immutable and a being mutable.

a** is an incrementer (equivalent to +=1) so I would have thought the answer would be -1?

Comment: That code does not compile anymore in Swift 3, `--` and `++` have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NOTE:* *That code worked only before Swift 3, in Swift 2 and lower, so this becomes more of a discussion about an algorithm.*

---

You have this code:

```
var a = 3
let b = a++
let c = -b
```

Let's take it line-by-line:

```
var a = 3
```

This declares a variable `a` and initializes it to `3`. The current value of `a` is `3`. Then:

```
let b = a++
```

This sets the value of `b` to the initial (current) value of `a`, which is `3` and uses the post-increment operator `++` to increase the value of `a` **after** the value of `b` is set to `3`. So `a` now equals `4`, but `b` is still `3`.

```
let c = -b
```

`c` is declared and initialized to `-b`, and `b` is currently `3`, so `c` becomes `-3`.

---

That being said, your code is equivalent to:

```
var a = 3
let b = a; a += 1
c = -b
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly that code does work anymore in Swift 3.0

in first statement    `var a = 3` makes the value of a = 3.
In the second statement `let b = a++` you are not actually increasing the value of a since its post increment operator. Hence value of b remains 3.
In the third statement the `let c = -b`  simply makes c= -3.